# Django Admin not Show Image from Imagefield

Tags: python, django, image

I want to show image like this [Django admin listview Customize Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708455/django-admin-listview-customize-column-name).
I've checked [Django Admin Show Image from Imagefield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307307/django-admin-show-image-from-imagefield), [Django - Display ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846290/django-display-imagefield), [Django - How can I display a photo saved in ImageField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830183/django-how-can-i-display-a-photo-saved-in-imagefield).

This is my models.py and admin.py.

```
#models.py
class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    master_id = models.IntegerField()
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tittle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    click = models.IntegerField()
    platform_time = models.DateTimeField()
    platform_type = models.IntegerField()
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField()
    enable = models.IntegerField()
    def image_tag(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.cover
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
    image_tag.allow_tags = True
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'movie'

#admin.py
class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'master_id', 'url', 'cover', 'tittle', 'duration', 'click', 'platform_time', 'platform_type', 'entry_date', 'enable')
    search_fields = ('id', 'tittle',)
    list_filter = ( 'enable', )
    readonly_fields = ( 'image_tag', )
```

Now, this is a part of my interface, there is no image_tag field. Further more, If I modify cover field to image_tag, the cover field is still not image visible.

[image: My interface]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an ImageField for cover instead of CharField and also change the image_tag return line:

```
cover = models.ImageField(upload_to = "images") #use the directory you want here
def image_tag(self):
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.cover.url
```

Also you have to add the image_tag field to list_display.
And make sure that django can find the upload_to directory.

Comment: Should I must use uploaded image? The image url I want to show is just a link to other website, does django have any idea to show that?

Comment: You would have to download the image from the other website first and then upload it. I do not think it would be a good idea to have a direct link to another website in there.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `'image_tag'` column (which contains `<img...>`) in `list_view`.

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote valid answer about images in django-admin listview for django 2.0.6.**

Here is link on my answer:
[Django: Display image in admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/django-display-image-in-admin-interface/51181825#51181825)

I hope it will help someone.