# Display image from ImageField by means of form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-uploads

**prelude**:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17846328/3872976)'s the simpliest way to display an ImageField. Lets assume I have 10 fields in my form and I don't wanna iterate over all of them in `template.html` just to check if it's an imageField and display it in a different way. I want to handle it via form or widget or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444076/3872976). So I want the leave template.html as it's bellow.

**template.html**

```html
<table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
</table>
```

And add to **models.py** an `image_tag` method:

```python
class UserProfile(Model):
  photo = ImageField(upload_to=PHOTO_DIRECTORY)
  contacts = TextField(null=True)
  ... others

  def image_tag(self):
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % self.photo.url

  image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
  image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

**forms.py**:

```python
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('contacts', 'photo', 'image_tag', ...others)
```

I get an error that `Unknown field(s) (image_tag) specified for UserProfile` which is fair enought.

I also tried to place it in `readonly_fields` but they don't display somehow. Do I have to create [list_view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993901/3872976)? If yes where should it be?

What do I miss here? Why the `image_tag` method should be a part of model instead of form? Model describes how data should persists in the database, not how it should present to user via form. This should be a part of form, shouldn't it?. Correct me please if I'm wrong. How do I solve the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't use methods in your ModelForm's fields list. I didn't try it but you might write a custom widget and set it as the default widget for photo field in your ModelForm.

Comment: Maybe decorating the method `image_tag` in your model with @property would help you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) mentioned the simplest solution was to create my own widget.

```
from string import Template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms import ImageField

class PictureWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        html =  Template("""<img src="$link"/>""")
        return mark_safe(html.substitute(link=value))

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = ImageField(widget=PictureWidget)
```

Comment: error : 'Template' object has no attribute 'substitute'

Comment: i'ved got invalid syntax for this. can you please clarify what needs to be imported, etc

Comment: thank you very much, atleast now it doesnt complain but no image appear thats because im using S3. how can I display the image from photo.url ?

Answer (score 6):

Let me improve this interesting question. I suggest to combine image input and image preview. Subclass FileInput widget and override render to concatenate additional html to display preview image and default input image html.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django import forms

class ImagePreviewWidget(forms.widgets.FileInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        input_html = super().render(name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs)
        img_html = mark_safe(f'<br><br><img src="{value.url}"/>')
        return f'{input_html}{img_html}'

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    photo = forms.ImageField(widget=ImagePreviewWidget,)
```

Comment: carefull with xss `f'{value.url}'`. this code is evaluated before `mark_safe`

Comment: @deathangel908 XSS attacks consist in injecting HTML (or JS) code in a page. `value.url` is taken from database and is safe

Comment: `value.url` is safe if it was before sanitised and validated. But if it was not it's better use string.Template of course

Comment: `value.url` looks better than `(media=settings.MEDIA_URL, link=value)`

Comment: You can put double quotes into a filename so this _is_ an issue if you allow user uploads.  You should use `django.utils.html.escape` on the value before inserting it.

Comment: I think the `mark_safe` isn't needed... And if it was, it'd need to wrap the value being returned for it to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment yet, thus I need to add this via an Answer. All credits to deathangel908 for this handy solution.

I'm using Django 2.1 and was struck with `TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'` error when trying the accepted answer. Solution to this problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039655/8002464

In short, the solution must be slightly changed for Django 2.1 and upwards and include `renderer=None`. Fully updated solution:

```py
from string import Template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms ImageField

class PictureWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        html =  Template("""<img src="$link"/>""")
        return mark_safe(html.substitute(link=value))

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = ImageField(widget=PictureWidget)
```

Btw. a quick small improvement, at least for my use-case was to add the media url. This way the images were actually shown instead of being lost in wrong urls. But this might only be because of how I set up my urls.

```py
from django.conf import settings

[...]
    html = Template("""<img src="$media$link"/>""")
    return mark_safe(html.substitute(media=settings.MEDIA_URL, link=value))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class ImagePreviewWidget(forms.widgets.FileInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        input_html = super().render(name, value, attrs=None, **kwargs)
        if value:
            img_html = mark_safe(
                f'<br><br><img src="{value.url}" width="200" />')
            return f'{input_html}{img_html}'
        return input_html
```

A slight change I would suggest if you want to use the same form for creating and updating. The if conditional will check if the value exists "is an update form" or else give you just the input field.