# Django TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

Tags: django

I've upgraded to Django 2.1, and I'm seeing this error when I load the admin interface:

> ```
> TypeError at /admin/foo/bar/1/change/
>
> render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
> ```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

This is almost certainly because of this backwards-incompatible [change in Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1):

> - Support for `Widget.render()` methods without the `renderer` argument is removed.

You may have subclassed `django.forms.widgets.Widget` in your code, or in the code of one of your dependencies. The code may look like this:

```
from django.forms import widgets

class ExampleWidget(widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        # ...
```

You need to fix the method signature of `render`, so that it looks like this:

```
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
```

Have a look at [the source code of `widgets.Widget`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py) if you want to check.

Comment: The current version of `django-datetime-widget` results in this when used with Django 2.1, although there is a pull request to fix it currently pending.

Comment: Except the traceback only lists core Django files, and no custom code, so it's unclear what widget is causing the error.

Comment: For me, was due to using https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/ with django 2.1, related to the widget I guess

Comment: Exactly right, frustrating that you can't get a decent stack trace on this error, as the root cause could be in any number of dependencies, or in your own code. Thankfully, an easy fix. I think the best way of finding this error is to just attempt a Ctrl+Shift+F on your project and look for the outdated method signature

Comment: @GwynEvans The project on PyPI [`django-datetime-widget`](https://pypi.org/project/django-datetime-widget/) hasn't been updated since 2014. The fork on PyPI [`django-datetime-widget2`](https://pypi.org/project/django-datetime-widget2/) seems to have a fix for Django >= 2.1

Comment: @Vadorequest The project on PyPI https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/ should support Django >= 2.1 now.

Answer (score 0):

Django is looking for a default renderer which can be set in `settings.py`

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're right. I think this by itself does not solve the error in the question. This sort of information is best added as a comment, but I realise that you don't have enough points yet to post comments, unfortunately. Bon courage!

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue with this problem is in **as_widget()** function of **BoundField**  class located at the location:

> **your_env_path/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py**

**existing_code**

```
def as_widget(self, widget=None, attrs=None, only_initial=False):
    #other code
    response = widget.render(
        name=self.html_initial_name if only_initial else self.html_name,
        value=value,
        attrs=attrs,
        renderer=self.form.renderer,
        )
    return response
 
#**update the above code to**
def as_widget(self, widget=None, attrs=None, only_initial=False):
    #other code
    try:
        response = widget.render(
        name=self.html_initial_name if only_initial else self.html_name,
        value=value,
        attrs=attrs,
        renderer=self.form.renderer,
        )
    except:
        response = widget.render(
        name=self.html_initial_name if only_initial else self.html_name,
        value=value,
        attrs=attrs
        )
    return response`
```

Answer (score -3):

Its version and signature incompatibility issue.
Go back to version - 2.0.8

> pip3 install Django==2.0.8

Comment: The old, accepted answer explains the incompatibility problem in much more detail, and also provides a reasonable solution. Downgrading Django to solve a minor issue doesn't constitute one.