# Django TypeError in version 2.2.1 : render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

Tags: python, django

I was actually solving this error by editing the django file "boundfield.py" by removing the renderer value.I also tried using django 2.0.x instead of the newest version as the older version is not having this issue. I know this is not the right way to solve this issue. Can anyone tell me what's the problem and is there any way that could help me solve this error if I am using django 2.2.1 ?

Comment: You need to actually show your code if you want us to help you

Comment: Please post full stack trace error.

Comment: I have developed a blog using django its showing this error when I am trying to add a new article to the blog... the form for adding article is having a rich text field using ckeditor and some character fields

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039654/django-typeerror-render-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-renderer  --- this one is similar to that of mine, but the answer was not clear for me

Comment: You haven't said which widget/field you are using for ckeditor, but it looks like it is not compatible with Django 2.1+.

Comment: I am using RichTextField  from ckeditor for adding content