# Render errors while trying to load Django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm receiving the error "render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'" while I try to run my Django web app. When I remove the [error](https://ibb.co/61mJcmV) shown, the app runs bu without some fields and looks like [this](https://ibb.co/hZzR9Rc.). When I take a look at the [forms.py](https://ibb.co/X8vMJJL) file, I see that the code doesn't have any errors. The rest of the file can be seen [here](https://ibb.co/W2k37Md). I can't seem to find where the problem is as I've only started with Django as a way of learning python. Can anyone point to me where the problem is and help me get a solution to it? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039654/django-typeerror-render-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-renderer)

Comment: can you post the code in views.py and forms.py file