# render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer' or crispy form

Tags: python-3.x, django

[add article views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fyxn.jpg)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZ2h.jpg)

[add article html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANNOQ.jpg)

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039654/django-typeerror-render-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-renderer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039654/django-typeerror-render-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-renderer)