# 'ImageField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to poplulate the fields in my "CreateDealerForm" for when I choose to edit. So far I can only populate the `featured_image` field and if I add `featured_image` to the widgets dictionary I get: `'ImageField' object has no attribute 'value_from_datadict'`

**forms.py**

```
class CreateDealerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dealer
        fields = ('name', 'phone','website', 'address', 'featured_image',)
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-name-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer name'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-phone-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer phone'}),
            'website': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-website-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer website'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dealer-address-field', 'placeholder': 'Dealer address'}),
            "featured_image": forms.ImageField(),
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def update_dealer_view(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Dealer, slug=slug)
    form = CreateDealerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        dealer = form.save(commit=False)
        dealer.save()
        return redirect('main:homepage_view')

    context = {
        "title": "Update - Dealer",
        "form": form,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/create/create_dealer.html", context=context)
```

Comment: Remove "featured_image" from widgets. If it's already a file or image field then you don't need to set it's widget manually

Comment: @IainShelvington the reason I was trying that is because I want to preview the image and I followed the answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764571/display-image-from-imagefield-by-means-of-form

Comment: `forms.ImageField` is not a widget, it is a form field

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the case when the request method is GET (when you first render the form for a user to edit the values). You need to handle this case and not pass data to the form or you will perform validation when you do not need to.

```
def update_dealer_view(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Dealer, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateDealerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            dealer = form.save()
            return redirect('main:homepage_view')
    else:
        form = CreateDealerForm(instance=instance)
    context = {
        "title": "Update - Dealer",
        "form": form,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/create/create_dealer.html", context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were fields in my defined model that matched the names of the widgets here. As I realized later, I had defined the wrong widget. ImageField does not accept widgets like other fields. Here is the wrong usage;

```
        widgets = {
        'name':         forms.TextInput(attrs=       {'class'  :'form-control','placeholder':'Kurs Adı'}),
        'description':  forms.Textarea(attrs=        {'class'  :'form-control','placeholder':'Kurs Açıklaması'}),
        'imageUrl':     forms.ImageField(),
        'date':         forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class'  :'form-control w-100 me-2 vw-100'}),
        'isActive':     forms.CheckboxInput(attrs=   {'class'  :'form-check-input w-100','style':'height: 40px;'}),
        'slug':         forms.TextInput(attrs=       {'class'  :'form-control','placeholder':'Boş bırakılabilir...'}),
        'category':     forms.Select(attrs=          {'class'  :'form-control'}),
```

Here is the correct usage;

```
widgets = {
'name':         forms.TextInput(attrs=       {'class'  :'form-control','placeholder':'Kurs Adı'}),
'description':  forms.Textarea(attrs =       {'class'  :'form-control','placeholder':'Kurs Açıklaması' }),
# there are no more wrong lines here
'date':         forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class'  :'form-control w-100 me-2 vw-100'}),
'isActive':     forms.CheckboxInput(attrs=   {'class'  :'form-check-input w-100','style':'height: 40px;'}),
'slug':         forms.TextInput(attrs=       {'class'  :'form-control','placeholder':'Boş bırakılabilir...'}),
'category':     forms.Select(attrs=          {'class'  :'form-control'}),
```

Comment: what code from what widgets?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).