# Display image from ImageField by means of form BUT with Upload button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I've been looking for a solution for a while. I saw this solution to show the image instead of just the link to the image: [Display image from ImageField by means of form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764571/display-image-from-imagefield-by-means-of-form/55059600#55059600?newreg=c9991682d47846c29631e41b5e922e45)

But now I need to add a button so they can upload a new picture.

Any solution to this? Thanks in advance!

THE CODE I HAVE ON FORMS.PY:

```py
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['profilePicture', 'coverPicture', 'description', 'job','organizationName','birthday', 'phone','country','city','church','education','website','blog','vlog', 'newsletter', 'mailNotification']
        labels = {
            'profilePicture':'<strong>Profile Picture</strong>',
            'coverPicture':'<strong>Cover Picture</strong>',
            'description':'<strong>Describe yourself</strong>', 
            'job':'<strong>Whats your job title/position?</strong>',
            'organizationName':'<strong>Name of the organization you belong</strong>',
            'birthday':'<strong>Birthday</strong> (YYYY-MM-DD)', 
            'phone':'<strong>Phone Number</strong>',
            'country':'<strong>Country</strong>',
            'city':'<strong>City</strong>',
            'church':'<strong>Name of the local church you attend</strong>',
            'education':'<strong>Tell us about your education</strong>',
            'website':'<strong>Website</strong>',
            'blog':'<strong>Blog</strong>',
            'vlog':'<strong>Vlog</strong>',
            'newsletter':'<strong>Suscribe to the Artventist newsletter</strong> (We hardly send one)',
            'mailNotification':'<strong>Would you like to recive email notifications regarding activity related to your account?</strong>'
            }
    mailNotification = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, label='<strong>Would you like to recive email notifications regarding activity related to your account?</strong>', choices=[(1, 'Instant'), (2, 'Daily'), (3, 'Weekly'),(0, 'No')])
    profilePicture = ImageField(widget=PictureWidget, label='<strong>Profile Picture</strong>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved this displaying the form field by field in the HTML and just calling the image by `<img src="url_to_picture">`

Answer (score 0):

I assume displaying images in table working fine.

Now add a form to the html template string where you are adding img tag.

The form (with action="update-img") consists of hidden input with id of old image and a submit button.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what you meant, I updated the quiestion above with the code I have on the forms.py