# Django How do I render an imageField attribute of a model in html?

Tags: django, web

I'm using the right code for inserting an ImageField in my html page but it still won't render the image, showing a broken link instead. This is the code:

```
<img src=" {{ model.imageFieldName.url }}>
```

I'm using 1.8 with debug=truee on my windows machine. I'm new to web development so any explanations would be appreciatied.

Comment: edit: forgot the trailing "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - How can I display a photo saved in ImageField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830183/django-how-can-i-display-a-photo-saved-in-imagefield)

Comment: Maybe you don't have MEDIA_URL or MEDIA_ROOT properly configured

Comment: @fasouto MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT are configured. I followed all the steps in the documentation. When I upload files I can see them in the MEDIA_ROOT (a local folder) I specified yet when I try to access the same I get broken links.

Comment: @Sayse That question had the asker using the field incorrectly. I am using it correctly AFAIK but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have your urls.py properly configured? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: @fasouto Oh wow totally missed that thanks! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to base64 string in core and put it into src like that:

Python:

```
import base64
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(your_image)
```

Django template:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {{ encoded_string }}">
```

Comment: While this could work, it's an terribly inefficient way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. For rendering images from DB you need to upload all images into **static/your_app/** directory. You may check it for example on the URL: **127.0.0.1:8000/static/your_app_name/uploads/name_of_image.svg** where you should see an image!
2. In your template use this syntax:
   `<src="/{{ object.image_field_name }}>` Notice that slash ! Without it you don't see the image.

Comment: This does not address images uploaded to the site via an imagefield. I have no issues rendering static images.

Comment: Wait, so you don't have a problem to render a image from models or what?